# Reconnect to a device after device crashed

Tags: java, usb, libusb

I have the following problem with the libusb-java and some self-made devices. 
It could happen that such a device disconnects from the USB Port because it drains to much power (as an example: i have a USB-LED Light which needs sometimes more than 500mA).
In this case the USB Controller will reset the device and the device will startup normaly again.

Now i cant really detect such a problem except for trying to reinit the device on every Exception. But thats not working...

On Every Exception i call my init Method again, which looks like this:

```
private void initDevice() {
USB.init();
this.dev = USB.getDevice(idVendor, idProduct);
}
```

The Problem with that is, this runs without any problem, but the i get this error message when i want to send new data:

```
LibusbJava.controlMsg: error sending control message: Protocol error
```

How do i can reinit the device? Do i have to reset the bus or something?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `open()` on the device - it is new for the system.